# Capacitance to Analog Voltage

Tags: analog, capacitance

I've been looking at theremins recently.  I've built a simple one using heterodyne oscillators, but I was wondering how to make a capacitance detector similar to the theremin's antennas.  Basically, a circuit that detects the capacitance between a antenna plate, and your hand (ground), and outputs an analog voltage depending on the capacitance.  I've thought about using a 555 timer as a variable pitch, and then feeding that into a pitch-to-voltage circuit.  But there must be a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. Heterodyning is an important part of how a Theremin works.

Keep in mind that the capacitance change caused by waving your hand near the antenna is a tiny fraction of the fixed/parasitic capacitance of the circuit overall, on the order of 0.2%.

The period of a 555 timer is directly proportional to capacitance, so a 0.2% change in capacitance results in a 0.2% change in period (or frequency). This would be difficult to detect and/or convert to a control voltage. If your 555 has a nominal period of 1 ms, you'll need to detect changes that cover a span of just 2 µs.

On the other hand, if you have a 1 MHz LC-tuned RF oscillator, a 0.2% change in capacitance will shift its frequency by 0.1%, or 1000 Hz. If you then mix this oscillator with a second oscillator that's fixed at 1 MHz, you get a beat frequency that varies from 0 to 1000 Hz, a range that's much easier to work with.

Comment: re: "fixed at 1 MHz". I thought I was oh so clever using a crystal oscillator for the reference... Turns out it's absolutely key that the reference is as similar as possible to the playable oscillator, so they drift (almost) identically with temperature variations!

Comment: Difficult is relative.  A cortex M4 with a 32 bit counter  running at 48 MHz would laugh at that 0.2% change.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: But that would only give you a resolution of about 1% (100 different values across the span) -- not really useful for music. Plus, you're assuming the 555 is that stable to begin with!

Comment: @BrianDrummond: There's also the phenomenon of [injection-locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injection_locking), which, depending on its strength, can be either helpful (maintaining a stable null) or harmful (making it impossible to produce low beat frequencies at all).

Comment: Injection locking also "pulls" the play oscillator unevenly throughout each "slip" cycle : this leads to badly built Theremins (most modern ones? mine at least!) having a raspy lower register rather than the rich woodwind tone of classic ones (sine wave + vacuum tube harmonics)

Answer (score 0):

Freescale has (had) a chip designed for a similar purpose (the [MC34940](http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MC34940.pdf)), but it does not seem to be available. There's nothing magic about it, you could implement the same functionality with jellybean analog parts.

As you can see, it's just an oscillator feeding an AC voltage divider and a detector.

Others have pointed out that you'd want very high resolution in the detected signal, for music, probably something better than the typical the on-chip ADC on a micro. I'll defer to their judgment on what is required.

[image]